# How can I create a LdapUserDetailsMapper which can take patterns for attribute values?

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-security-ldap

I have created a custom `LdapUserDetailsMapper` class to map extended properties to a custom `UserDetails` class that contains extra properties for things like `displayName`, `telephoneNumber` and `department` to name a few. I managed to populate these properties by accessing the properties against the `DirContextOperation`, i.e.

```
res.givenName = ctx.getStringAttribute("givenName");
```

I do not wish to hard-code this however and would like to have these properties configurable, which is fine, though I also want to use LDAP expressions to return a value resulting from that expression, i.e.

```
res.givenName = ctx.getStringAttribute("givenName + ' ' + sn");
```

This of course does not work. I could manually parse the pattern and retrieve the components prior to any concatenation but this sounds like work that I imagine the framework could already provide.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution I would imagine could work is to use the [Spring Expression Language](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html). Implement your own [`EvaluationContext`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/expression/EvaluationContext.html) that takes a `DirContextOperations` instance as root object and forwards porperty reads to its `getStringAttribute()` method. The expressions in this case wouldn't exactly be LDAP expressions, but I guess SpEL is more powerful, so it might be even better.